# Daterange with filter over a column

Tags: sql

I'm stuck with a simple question.

I have to filter a set of data within a range.
Example

```
Datemin 2011  
Datemax 2014
```

Got to filter all Data from a specific numeric column(xyz) within that daterange.

It works with one attribute.
Lets say:

```
where xyz = 20 AND Datemin AND Datemax --<< works
```

but

```
where xyz = 20 AND xyz = 24 AND Datemin AND Datemax --<< doesn't work
```

and this

```
where xyz = 20 OR xyz = 24 AND Datemin AND Datemax
```

Daterange for `xyz = 20` works, but not for `xyz = 24` - there I get all dates from `2000-today`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. `AND Datemin AND Datemax` is invalid SQL.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help a lot.

Comment: Try `where (xyz = 20 OR xyz = 24) AND Datemin AND Datemax`

Comment: That works too and is a better solution for my code, nice..great thxs

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have a date column.  I would expect the code to look something like this:

```
where xyz = 20 AND
      yearcol >= Datemin AND
      yearcol <= Datemax
```

If you want "or", then use `in`:

```
where xyz in (20, 24) AND
      yearcol >= Datemin AND
      yearcol <= Datemax
```

Or use parentheses.  But `in` is much simpler.

Actually, this assumes that you have a column with the *year*.  Your comparisons are integers and they look like years.

Comment: Thxs Gordon..i forgot the IN statement, damn....
Now it works..big thxs.